# elasticsearch create or update document using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulk, elasticsearch-helpers

I am using [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/) for elasticsearch operation.

I am trying for [`elasticsearch.helpers.bulk`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) to create or update multiple records.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
es = Elasticsearch()

data = [
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_op_type": "create",
        "_id": 3,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_op_type": "create",
        "_id": 4,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_op_type": "create",
        "_id": 5,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_op_type": "create",
        "_id": 6,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
]


print helpers.bulk(es, data)
```

Is there any way to perform this operation?

Now we can give only `_op_type` as `create` or `update`. If we give `update` and record is not exist, then it will raise error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 37, in <module>
    print helpers.bulk(es, data)
  File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 182, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 155, in streaming_bulk
    raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors), errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: ('4 document(s) failed to index.', [{u'update': {u'status': 404, u'_type': u'external', u'_id': u'3', u'error': u'DocumentMissingException[[customer][-1] [external][3]: document missing]', u'_index': u'customer'}}, {u'update': {u'status': 404, u'_type': u'external', u'_id': u'4', u'error': u'DocumentMissingException[[customer][-1] [external][4]: document missing]', u'_index': u'customer'}}, {u'update': {u'status': 404, u'_type': u'external', u'_id': u'5', u'error': u'DocumentMissingException[[customer][-1] [external][5]: document missing]', u'_index': u'customer'}}, {u'update': {u'status': 404, u'_type': u'external', u'_id': u'6', u'error': u'DocumentMissingException[[customer][-1] [external][6]: document missing]', u'_index': u'customer'}}])
```

Comment: have you tried using `index` as `op_type` instead of `create` and `update` ?

Comment: @Val, as per `helpers.bulk` document, we have to give `index`, I also tried your solution, its give `ValidationError`, `elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, u'ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]')`

Comment: That's weird... You're sure you have `"_op_type": "index"`?

Comment: You can check docs for this method http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk

Comment: Also have you tried without specifying `_op_type` at all, I think it will default to `index` by itself.

Comment: @Val, thanks, it works :). Without `_op_type` it take it as `create` or `update`. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [`_bulk` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) documentation, you can and should use the `index` action for this, provided your documents always have the same identifiers.

`create` is useful when creating documents the first time, and `update` is more meant for doing partial and/or scripted updates.

You can also not specify any `_op_type` at all and `index` will be taken by default.

Answer (score 5):

I tried solution suggested by @Val and it works as charm.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
es = Elasticsearch()

data = [
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": 3,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": 4,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": 5,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
    {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": 6,
        "doc" : {"name": "test"}
    },
]


print helpers.bulk(es, data)
```